# How to create a link for Custom Search API for "Standard Search Element"

Tags: google-custom-search

I am trying to get a search request from Google by Custom Search API, this product few types of API, some of them are free, more detail [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/overview). I know how to create a URL for Custom Search JSON API which has a limit of 100 queries.
Custom Search JSON API URL:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=lectures
```

But how to create a link for Standard Search Element which is free?
What is need to change inside the GET URL or maybe need to disable something inside the programmable search engine console?

```
https://programmablesearchengine.google.com/
```

I didn't change standard settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your engine.

https://support.google.com/programmable-search/answer/4513882?hl=en&ref_topic=4513742

Then you can use it for free.
If you want to use JSON API, you need to have an API Key which using it will come with cost.
Pricing: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview